# iOS app displays previous values when returning to app

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm new to iOS programming (with very strong Java background). I started a simple app using **Xcode 11** with **Swift 5.1** for **iOS 13**. I just need the user to input a host and port on the the single page app, that's it (with a test button to send a JSON request).

For some reason, both on the simulator or on my phone, after changing a value in a text field, closing (home-button click) then returning on the app displays the old (original) value. But somehow, the bound value (in UserDefaults) is correct. The test() method uses the last input value (as well as the app share extensions).
I try to keep things as simple as possible:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
 
    @EnvironmentObject var config: MyConfig
    @EnvironmentObject var service: MyService
    
    var body: some View {

        // proxy the text field String to allow on-the-fly set
        let portProxy = Binding<String>(
            get: {
                print("proxy get \(self.config.port)")
                return "\(self.config.port)" },
            set: {
                print("proxy set \($0)")
                if let value = NumberFormatter().number(from: $0) {
                    self.config.port = value.intValue
                }
            }
        )
        
        return VStack() {
            Text(verbatim: "Kodi Settings")
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.medium)
            Divider()
            HStack() {
                TextField("Host", text: $config.host)
            }
            Divider()
            HStack() {
                TextField("Port", text: portProxy)
                    .keyboardType(.asciiCapableNumberPad)
            }
            Divider()
            Button(action: {
                self.service.test()
            }) {
                Text("Test")
            }
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding(.all)
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class KodiConfig: ObservableObject {
    private enum Keys {
        static let host = "host"
        static let port = "port"
    }

    private let defaults: UserDefaults

    init(_ defaults: UserDefaults = .standard) {
        self.defaults = defaults
        
        defaults.register(defaults: [
            Keys.host: "host.local",
            Keys.port: 8080
        ])
    }

    var host: String {
        set { defaults.set(newValue, forKey: Keys.host) }
        get { defaults.string(forKey: Keys.host)! }
    }

    var port: Int {
        set {
            print("setting port: \(newValue)")
            defaults.set(newValue, forKey: Keys.port) }
        get {
            let ret = defaults.integer(forKey: Keys.port)
            print("port is \(ret)")
            return ret
        }
    }
}
```

Now I keep on getting the following error|warn|debug messages on the console when I press the home button. Not that double press and kill the background app has the app reload with correct values:

> 2019-10-29 10:07:33.880779+0100 Send2Kodi[1929:114121] Can't find keyplane that supports type 11 for keyboard iPhone-PortraitChoco-NumberPad; using 25671_PortraitChoco_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default
>
> 2019-10-29 10:07:48.956270+0100 Send2Kodi[1929:114121] Can't end BackgroundTask: no background task exists with identifier 2 (0x2), or it may have already been ended. Break in UIApplicationEndBackgroundTaskError() to debug.
>
> 2019-10-29 10:07:51.663279+0100 Send2Kodi[1929:114121] [Snapshotting] Snapshotting a view (0x10623e8b0, _UIReplicantView) that has not been rendered at least once requires afterScreenUpdates:YES.

Is there anything to manually do when the scene is entering background? Apple doc seems to imply that everything is magic. Note that this behaviour is the same for both the int and the string field. It doesn't seem related to the proxy value var.

Comment: I don't understand your issue. Backgrounding the app does nothing to the values in the memory and you seems to know it. So what is wrong?

Comment: returning to the app displays in the text boxes the values BEFORE the changes, the same values as when I first entered the app. It's like: 1) open fresh app -> value is 80 2) change val to 8080 3) background app 4) open app again 5) displayed value is 80 (but in UserDefaults it's 8080)